# How do I figure out the size of nuts and bolt in this picture?

Tags: fireplace

I can't see any markings on the nut(?). 
I just need to find the diameter and thread pitch so I can replace my fire place log set.

[image: size]

Comment: By far the easiest way to find out is to disassemble it and take the fittings with you to the hardware store.  It looks like just a flare fitting on the end of the copper gas line, so if push comes to shove you can just replace the entire fitting.

Comment: The thread pitches will be "standard onm these type of fittings, the replacements will have the same thread. If you meaqsured the outside diameter of the copper pipe and the diameter of the elbow where it goes into the log set will give a better idea of the sizes you have. For example 1/2" copper pipe will be about 9/16"- 5/8" the "black pipe" street elbow will have the same issue, 3/8" pipe will measure approx. 1/2" outside dia. 1/2" will be about 5/8" to 11/16". due to the thicker wall sizes

Comment: Putting a ruler in the photo next to the pipe, will give folks a size reference.